# A conjecture about filters

Tags: order-theory, filters

Let $\mathfrak{F}(S)$ denotes the set of filters (including the improper filter) on a poset $S$, ordered *reversely* to set theoretic inclusion of filters. Let $Da$ for a lattice element $a$ denote its sublattice $\{ x \mid x \leq a \}$. Let $Z(X)$ denotes the set of complemented elements of the lattice $X$.

**Conjecture** $\mathfrak{F}(Z(D\mathcal{A}))$ is order-isomorphic to $D\mathcal{A}$ for every filter $\mathcal{A}$ on a set $U$ (and the lattice $\mathfrak{F}(\mathscr{P}U)$). If they are isomorphic, find an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have proved this conjecture.

[See my book](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/volume-1.pdf). Currently it is theorem number 598.